# option window size texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I have a very strange phenomenon. The option window of texmaker is too big for my screen (just this window...). When I want to resize it, there is no problem with horizontal rescaling, but when I try to reduce the vertical size of this window, in order to reach the "ok" button, then the window suddenly disappear under the screen. I have to hold & click "window + shift + top arrow to make it reappear...

Is someone has an explaination about this and mostly a solution?

Comment: I have similar problem in TeXstudio in my laptop, because height of screen. What you can do is to maximize the Options window.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I can't maximize it, there is no button on the top of the window (except "?" and "close") and even the shortcuts don't work.

Comment: What about double click on window title bar?

Comment: Nothing's happening. When I change the screen's resolution to 1440*900, I see the entire window and I can change its size, but when I come back to the native resolution, 1920*1080 the problem's still there. However, I found a way to change the option with another resolution, that's a first baby step!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Changing the screen resolution is one option, but you can also change the setting "Size of text, apps... " to 100% in the displays menu (from the default 150%), resulting everything being much smaller. As a result you can see the entire options window, but of course everything else is much smaller, too. I actually prefer that to the original setting but I guess it's personal ;).